# Excel File with more than 100k rows has errors

Tags: microsoft-excel, spreadsheet

i would like to know if there is a way to fix excel's problem:

i have a file with more than 100k rows, and everytime i am using filters in columns it doesn't really show everything after, there is a bug, its missing some rows sometimes which forces me to restart my work to see what i missed.

Does anyone know, what are the best ways to optimize such files and what features can be used ?

Is cutting the file into 3-4different files the way to go? I wonder if that is because the file is too big

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Adding filters in A column, uncheck 1,2,3 only show 4, then column B adapts and shows only those whose data is in the same row as 4. But when i do the reverse, there is data missing

Comment: Can you add screenshots of the data in both filtered states to show how some data you would expect to show up isn't. My first thought is that some data in B is different than you think it is so the filter isn't catching them. There are a few ways to figure that out.

Comment: Unfortunately, that is just how excel works. If you have 2,000 unique values in column B excel will only about the first 1,000 (I don't have the exact number, but you can google that). Keep in mind, your work around only works if you first sort column B...

Comment: Have you considered using a database?

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/not-all-items-are-displayed-in-the-autofilter-pivottable-list-4ad03761-b54e-6f91-640f-fbee648cd8f1 This is a known issues in Excel, you can try to use Access to open large data.

Answer (score 0):

I created a 100,000 row range with six columns, set column filters, then looked to see which rows Excel would let me work on.

It showed "checkable" choices down to and including 10,002. Interestingly, when I clicked on the "Not all items showing" ... spot... it gave the following error message:

```
This column has more than 10,000 unique items. Only the first 10,000 unique items are displayed.
```

(It was not displaying row 1's entry as the filter functionality seems to regard the first row as a header row, period, so it actually displayed 10,001, not 10,002, and to make it interesting, "10,001" is not "10,000" as stated.)

I removed the extra columns to see if it was variable based upon range size and got the same message, so it's not directly a matter of memory usage.

So, on the face of it with no more information, yes, you will need to break the data into several tables to work with it as is. How many will depend upon the number of UNIQUE values in the column/s you filter.

However, it all depends upon your work and what your organization permits. For instance, if you work DIRECTLY ON the data, so find a record, then change or delete material in the row/s or add/delete the row/s itself/themselves, then you must break the data apart.

If, however, you use the information found to do work other than on the actual data itself, you can set up a working table using the `FILTER()` function to find and present the data you need. (Its results can themselves be filtered.)

Lots of possibilities there, and the columns can be adjusted interestingly:  in whatever order you wish, lose some columns, make columns appear more than once, that kind of thing, if you wrap it with `INDEX()` (of for some, but not all that flexibility, with another `FILTER()`).

Stepping out past those "in universe" extremes, you can do many kinds of work with and on the data using Power Query. And PQ can "filter" the material you have to work with more finely and more robustly than Excel's filtering functionality can. And can output to a Table you can use if you prefer or need to mix approaches (do the record selection (and column selection and ordering for that matter) in PQ, then output to a Table to work on as you are used to doing.

It all depends upon the exact work you do.

And if good with VBA, and allowed to use it, VBA can do almost anything of this kind and be tweaked to suit your needs precisely.

So depending upon the work you do, and your organizational considerations, you may have to break the table into pieces, or may not have to at all.

If you do, the key is how many UNIQUE items there are in the filtered column. So even though the limit per data range filtered seems to be "10,000" it may be you only need, say, two tables, not three/four, or ten or more due to some data items not being unique.